# latex math font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I am writing mathematical document and I want to change the font in math mode

This is what I currently get

[image: what I get]

and this is what I want

[image: what I want]

How should I change? Following is my latex code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}                           
\usepackage{amsmath, bm, listings, pxfonts, enumitem, geometry, titlesec, array, makecell}
\geometry{margin=0.8in}                                                                                         
\title{Statistics Notes}                                
\author{}                                  
\date{}                                                                                                         
\begin{document}                                        
\maketitle

\[\left(\bar{x}-\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\bar{x}+\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second image is the default math font in LaTeX (cm math), you want to undo the customizations done in the document class you're using. Please add a MWE showing the document setup and packages you use that caused this behavior.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the first one looks like URW Palladio or a font based on it, like TeX Gyre Pagella or other Palatino clone. If you're loading `tgpagella`, `mathpazo`, `pxfonts`, `kpfonts` or `newpxmath`/`newpxtext`, remove those packages. (I guess it could also be Asana Math.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please show your code, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, then only experts can give suggestions to meet the requirement exactly, else you may not get the correct solution...

Comment: It’s not possible to tell exactly what solution you need without your sharing [a MWE.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) This doesn’t have to be the full document, just the shortest excerpt that reproduces the behavior you’re asking about. The answer will probably be to remove some font packages. (If they’re loaded in a style file that you’re required to use, things get harder.)

Comment: Hi, I have edit the question to include the code.

Comment: `pxfonts` was one of the packages frabjous mentioned as being a possible source of your problem.  Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Thank you! I remove pxfonts and add amsfonts then it works!
Sorry for the newbie question, and I am glad to joint this community :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Palatino (style) font for text while retaining CM for maths and have a recent TeX Distribution use the newpxtext package.